# How do I tell python class method to reference its own fields?

Tags: python

This is a simple problem that is hard for me to put into words because I'm not too familiar with Python's syntax. I have a class called "Quadrilateral" that takes 4 points, and I'm trying to make a method called "side_length" that I want to use to compute the length of the line between two of the vertices on the quadrilateral:

```
import math


class Point:
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("Point Constructor")

    def to_string(self):
        return "{X: " + str(self.x) + ", Y: " + str(self.y) + "}"


class Quadrilateral:
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    p3 = 0
    p4 = 0

    def __init__(self, p1=Point(), p2=Point(), p3=Point(), p4=Point()):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
        self.p4 = p4
        print("Quadrilateral Constructor")

    def to_string(self):
        return "{P1: " + self.p1.ToString() + "}, " + "{P2: " + self.p2.ToString() + "}, " + \
           "{P3: " + self.p3.ToString() + "}," + "{P4: " + self.p4.ToString() + "}"

    def side_length(self, p1, p2):
        vertex1 = p1
        vertex2 = p2
        return math.sqrt((vertex2.x - vertex1.x)**2 + (vertex2.y - vertex1.y)**2)

    def perimeter(self):
        side1 = self.side_length(self.p1, self.p2)
        side2 = self.side_length(self.p2, self.p3)
        side3 = self.side_length(self.p3, self.p4)
        side4 = self.side_length(self.p4, self.p1)
        return side1 + side2 + side3 + side4
```

Right now I'm calling the side_length method by explicitly telling it to use the quadrilateral's points, but is there a way to implicitly use just "p1" and "p2" without the need to tell it to use the quadrilateral's points (I'm using q.p1 and q.p2 when I just want to use p1 and p2 and imply python to use the quadrilateral's points)? I've realized it's basically a static method, and I want it to use the class fields rather than take in any point.

```
q = Quadrilateral(p1, p2, p3, p4)
print(q.to_string())
print("Side length between " + q.p1.to_string() + " and " + q.p2.to_string() + ": " + str(q.side_length(q.p1, q.p2)))
print("Perimeter is: " + str(q.perimeter()))
```

I also have other redundancy issues- like are there better ways to go about initially defining the points p1, p2, p3, p4 in the quadrilateral class, and is there a simpler way to compute the perimeter of the quadrilateral?

Comment: don't define class variables and instance variables separately: Just use one or the other, in your case instance variables (they begin with `self`) work just fine. This allows you to access the instance variables using `self.__some_variable_here__`

Comment: You already have `self` so just get it from your `self`.

Comment: As a side note, instead of defining a `to_string` method and having to do `print(q.to_string())` everywhere, just define a `__str__` method; then you can just `print(q)`. Even better, that means you can use string formatting to combine strings together. For example, `Quadritaleral.__str__` could just `return f'<{p1}, {p2}, {p3}, {p4}>'` and this will do the same thing as `return '<' + str(p1) + ', ' + str(p2) + ', ' + str(p3) + ', ' + str(p4) + '>'`.

Comment: To add to JacobiRR's point, occasionally you _do_ want to use class attributes as default values for instance attributes—but in that case, you want them to actually be useful default values. Having an attribute that's supposed to be a `Point` instance, but whose fallback class attribute value is `0`, which isn't a `Point`, is just asking for trouble. At any rate, that "occasionally" doesn't apply here—you've got an `__init__` that already has, and stores, default values, so that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a nearly perfect question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but I'll put my edits anyway.

To note at start:

- avoid classes until you can
- try writing less junk/support/boilerplate code and more fun code
- recylce whatever python has to offer before making something new
- write at least a tiny test or an `assert`
- skip the rules above while learning

Here is my edit of your code, hope you find some useful ideas/clues:

```
# not needed
#import math

class Point:
#FIXME: delete this and do some reading on class attributes
#    x = 0.0
#    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#FIXME: use __str__ method for this
#    def to_string(self):
#        return "{X: " + str(self.x) + ", Y: " + str(self.y) + "}"

    def distance(self, p):
        return ((self.x - p.x) ** 2 + (self.y - p.y) ** 2) ** .5                    


class Quadrilateral:
# FIXME: same  as in class Point
#    p1 = 0
#    p2 = 0
#    p3 = 0
#    p4 = 0

# FIXED: you do not want anything undefined for constructor
#    def __init__(self, p1=Point(), p2=Point(), p3=Point(), p4=Point()):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3, p4):
        # saving some typing 
        self.points = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
#        self.p2 = p2
#        self.p3 = p3
#        self.p4 = p4
#        print("Quadrilateral Constructor")

# FIXME: please make some life easier
#    def to_string(self):
#        return "{P1: " + self.p1.ToString() + "}, " + "{P2: " + self.p2.ToString() + "}, " + \
#           "{P3: " + self.p3.ToString() + "}," + "{P4: " + self.p4.ToString() + "}"

    def side(self, vertex_n):
        # TODO: elaborate some protection against wrong *vertex_n*
        a, b = self.points[vertex_n], self.points[vertex_n-1]
        return a.distance(b)          

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return sum([self.side(i) for i in range(4)])
        # any duplicated code is a sign of danger: somehtign is going wrong!
        #side1 = self.side_length(self.p1, self.p2)
        #side2 = self.side_length(self.p2, self.p3)
        #side3 = self.side_length(self.p3, self.p4)
        #side4 = self.side_length(self.p4, self.p1)
        #return side1 + side2 + side3 + side4

pts = [Point(x, y) for x, y in [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)]]        
assert Quadrilateral(*pts).perimeter == 4
```

As an excercise you can make a parent class Polygon and inherit Quadrilateral from it.

---

*Update*: in the original answer I wrote:

```
# COMMENT: class Point better be a namedtuple, please google it and use it
```

That sounded too categorical to a respected reader, who noted:

> Whether Point is mutable depends on what you want to do with points in your app. Usually go with immutable by default if you don't have any reason not to.

In other words, it is prudent not to rush into `namedtuple` unless you are sure the the data structure should not change. To me that sounds overly protective, but you cannot deny the logic your choice of data structure depends on how you plan to use it.

For converting something to `namedtuple` please see a nice example of refactoring at [Raymond Hettinger - Beyond PEP 8 -- Best practices for beautiful intelligible code](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=2641).

Other suggested direction for thought is using `dataclass`, available in standard library starting [Python 3.7](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes).

Comment: I don't think all of these recommendations are necessarily good. There's nothing wrong with an initializer taking default values—having a "zero point" constructible with `Point()` is certainly not nonsensical. Also, you really need to decide whether points, quadrilaterals, etc. are supposed to be mutable or immutable first, and only then decide how to implement them. `namedtuple` makes sense if you want immutable, but not mutable. And if `Point` is a `namedtuple` (or a `@dataclass` or `@attr.s` or…), then `Quadrilateral` almost certainly should be as well.

Comment: The question of a class hierarchy is another thing that should only come after deciding on mutability—e.g., with immutable values, Rectangle is a subtype of Quadrilateral and Square isa subtype of Rectangle, but with mutable values, that isn't true.

Comment: @abarnert There is definitely quite a bit add on Point-Rectangle-Poligon theme, but looking at your poinst quiclkly: 1) defaults are ok, but enforcing a value on Point() is even better, unless you want to get stuck at (0,0)  in some universe 2) given a choice of mutable or not, `Point` would rather be not 3) `Quadrilateral` does not have explicit setter methods and you can pretend it is immutable 4) `@dataclass` better waits till python 3.7

Comment: 1) You won't get "stuck" at `(0, 0)` any more than you get stuck at `""` because that's the default value returned by `str()`. 2) Whether `Point` is mutable depends on what you want to do with points in your app. Usually go with immutable by default if you don't have any reason not to, but that's just as true for `Quadrilateral` or any other type as for `Point`. 3) Not having explicit setter methods definitely doesn't mean immutable, especially in Python, where attributes are normally public. 4) You can use the backport for 3.6, or use `attrs`—not to mention that 3.7 is only 2 weeks away.

Comment: 1) you do not do `x=''; x ='abc'` if you want 'abc', or do you @abarnert? 2) are you sure you need to discuss it with me, not OP? 3) really? show me your approach to immutable `Quadrilateral` and I'll show you to mutate it 4) why not try teaching that to OP?

Comment: 1) No, but you do `x=''` and then later `if something: x='abc'` if you want a default value when `x` isn't set. I don't know why you think default values are an unusual or bad thing when most builtin and standard library types have them, including `int` and `str`. 2) Yes, because you're the one giving inappropriate advice, not the OP. 3) The same is true for `Point`. I can even show you how to mutate `str` if you want. That doesn't mean you don't design them to be immutable. 4) There are already 4 answers to the question, and it isn't even really a question; my 2 comments to the OP are enough.

Comment: @abarnert: 1) all-default class is not bad, it just smells bad, as it opens the road to ugly semi-defined constructs such as `Point(p1, p2)`, which is even worse for an immutable. also makes a such class very similar `lazy class`, revieving a bit of blame in Fowler's Refactoring. see also for examlpe at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160689/is-it-a-better-practice-pre-initialize-attributes-in-a-class-or-to-add-them-alo. You should not advise instantinating classes with all defaults to anyone  whom you wish some good, especially at novice level

Comment: @abarnet: 2)  _`Whether Point is mutable depends on what you want to do with points in your app.`_ - in my best understanding of the English langage that relates to requirements and problem owner, which I'm not.

Comment: 2 and 3) Your logic is quite untraceable - you seem to advodate unmutable type, but have a had time noticing anyone agree with you. I'd fill a separate question on `int` mutation 4) seems to die out, luckily

Comment: I'm beginning to think the language barrier is insurmountable here. Let me just make one point: You say "in my best understanding of the English langage that relates to requirements and problem owner, which I'm not." And yet, you suggest that "class Point better be a namedtuple, please google and use it". Either you don't know enough about the problem to know whether Point should be immutable, in which case this is bad advice, or you do know enough, in which case claiming that you're not the problem owner to avoid discussion is disingenuous.

Comment: maybe it is not English - is `namedtuple` mutable?

Comment: `namedtuple` classes are immutable. So, don't tell someone they'd better use `namedtuple` unless you know that their class should be immutable.

Comment: How is above compatible with your suggestion _Usually go with immutable by default_? This I really don't understand - when it is your suggestion it is gold, when other people suggest it, it is wrong/inappropriate.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy recommending that people start their class designs by assuming immutability if they don't have any reason to go mutable. (Although I do think it's worth actually explaining that instead of just insisting on it.) That's very different from insisting that people must use `namedtuple` even though you claim you don't know whether their classes should be immutable. If you don't understand why it's different, I honestly don't know how to explain it to you.

Comment: I see, you were unhappy with 'better be', which sounds insisting, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
def side_length(self, side):
    if side == 1:
        vertex1 = self.p1
        vertex2 = self.p2
    elif side == 2:
        vertex1 = self.p2
        vertex2 = self.p3
    elif side == 3:
        vertex1 = self.p3
        vertex2 = self.p4
    elif side == 4:            
        vertex1 = self.p4
        vertex2 = self.p1
    else:
        print("Error! No side {}".format(side))
        return None
    return math.sqrt((vertex2.x - vertex1.x)**2 + (vertex2.y - vertex1.y)**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing how you keep track of your points. Rather than having four separate attributes with numbers in the names, use a list. Then you can pass an index to your `side_lengths` method:

```
def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    self.points = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

def side_length(self, n):
    vertex1 = self.points[n]
    vertex2 = self.points[n-1] # if the index becomes -1, that's ok, it will wrap around
    return math.sqrt((vertex2.x - vertex1.x)**2 + (vertex2.y - vertex1.y)**2)

def perimeter(self):
    return sum(side_length(i) for i in range(4))
```

I'd also suggest that you rename your `to_string` functions to `__str__`, as Python will call that method automatically for you in some cases (such as when you're printing an object).